# relation between subsets of power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there some theorem or proposition that shows the following:

> for all sets $A\in P(S)$ with $|A|\geq 2$ there exists an $x\in A$ such that $\{x\}\in P(S)$

For example, let $S=\{a, b, c\}$.  The corresponding power set is $\{\{\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$.  By inspection, each of $\{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}$ has as a member least one of $a, b, c$, and the singletons containing those three elements are all elements of $P(S)$. How would one go about constructing a formal proof of this?

Comment: actually, I meant cardinality $ \geq 2$

Comment: The statement is "for all sets $A\in P(S)$ with $|A|\geq 2$ there exists an $x\in A$ such that $\{x\}\in P(S)$, correct?

Comment: exactly what I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

If $A \in P(S), A \subseteq S$, so any element of $A$ is also an element of $S$, so the singleton set containing that element is an element of $P(S)$

Answer (score 1):

Let's write this precisely:

> For all sets, $S$, and all $A\in P(S)$, if $A\neq\emptyset$ then $\exists x\in A$ such that $\{x\}\in P(S)$

Notice that I've made the condition even more general. This proposition is true in this expanded form. Now let's prove it:

Recall that $B\in P(S)\iff B\subseteq S$. Therefore we can rephrase this a

> For all sets $S$, if $A\subseteq S$ and $A\neq\emptyset$ then $\exists x\in A$ such that $\{x\}\subseteq S$.

This follows immediately from transitivity of $\subseteq$. Let $x$ be any element of $A$. Then $$\{x\}\subseteq A\subseteq S\Rightarrow \{x\}\subseteq S$$ the first $\subseteq$ holds by construction of $x$ and the second holds by supposition. The requirement $A\neq\emptyset$ allows us to pick an $x\in A$ in the first place.

Comment: this may seem naïve, but isn't it $\{B\} \subseteq P(S)$?

Comment: @doctorjay That is also true, but that's not the equivalent statement that I am interested in. All three statements mean the same thing

Comment: Question answered thoroughly and satisfactorily.  Where can I find an explanation of $B \in P(S) \Leftrightarrow B \subseteq S$?

Comment: @doctorjay A power set is the set of all subsets. That's precisely what it means. So of course an element of a powerset will be a subset of the original set.

Comment: I will stare for awhile

Comment: @doctorjay have you figured it out yet? Maybe I can try to be more helpful

Comment: I was cut off by the Stack Police.  Anyway, what I'm puzzling over is not your elegant first-principle proof, but the following: If $S=\{a, b,c\}$, then $P(S)=\{\{\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{ab\}, \{ac\}, \{bc\}, \{abc\}\}$

Comment: I was cut off by the Stack Police.  Anyway, what I'm puzzling over is not your elegant first-principle proof, which makes perfect sence but the following: If $S=\{a, b,c\}$, then $P(S)=\{\{\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{ab\}, \{ac\}, \{bc\}, \{abc\}\}$. $\{a\} \in P(S),$ but $a$, not $\{a\} \subseteq S$.  Otherwise, the following statement is true:  "An single element of a set is the same as the subset of that set containing only that member."  Please excuse my ignorance.  I'm trained as an (horrors) engineer, not as a mathematician

Comment: Never, mind, my staring just paid off!  I'm confusing $\in$ and $\subseteq$!

Comment: @doctorjay okay, cool. It sounds like you're getting it.